# CSS Border-Radius Changes on Hover

Tags: css

I can't figure out why the CSS `border-radius` changes on hover on this div: http://jsfiddle.net/7pujbpn0/

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.thumbnail {
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Opera */
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
     border-radius: 13px;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 13px;
}

.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
   -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
   transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="image">
        <img  src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="Some awesome text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `border-radius` is set to 13px. I'm just trying to achieve a simple zoom effect on the image when you hover over a div.

Comment: Post your code in your question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you add:

```
    .thumbnail {overflow: hidden;}
```

it should do the trick.

Here is a link to an updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7pujbpn0/2/

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, glad it was what you were looking for.